# Is it a security flaw to start new process in server?

Tags: c#, .net, web

In a web application .NET, I had to convert html to the pdf on the fly. I played around with some open source projects . Finally I found wkhtmltopdf .On the server side my app will invoke a server side process of wkhtmlpdf and passes the argument and presents the user with the pdf file.

How bad is this approach from security stand point? Is it more vulnerable to bots?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose the spawned program has some buffer overflow error when given untrustworthy input, that causes arbitrary code to run. On the good side: hey, the arbitrary code is now running in another process, not the server process. On the bad side: the arbitrary code now has all the rights that the process has.

Isolating subsystems to their own process is a good practice but don't stop there. Use defense in depth.

- Start the new process with the least amount of privilege it needs to operate correctly. That way if there is a successful attack on it, the damage is limited.
- Sanitize the inputs to the process, particularly if they come from a untrustworthy source. Make sure the files are a reasonable size and contain reasonable data.

You want a successful attack to have to jump through a dozen impossible hoops, not just one.

Joe's point about denial of service is also a good one to think about.

Comment: For more information about the "Start the new process with the least amount of privilege it needs to operate correctly" part I recommend learning about "[Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0.aspx)". Here is a good [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5724/Understanding-NET-Code-Access-Security) that helped me out when I was first learning it. This lets you run the code without things like IO access rights or blocking the use of PInvoked code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Indeed, though I note that CAS only applies to managed code. For unmanaged code you could use something like `CreateProcessWithToken` or `CreateProcessAsUser` to create a process associated with a less-privileged security token or a less-privileged user, if the spawning process has more rights than you would like to pass on.

Answer (score 5):

It's vulnerable to people swamping your server and DOSsing it. You could place requests in a message queue, and then have a service processing items off the queue. This means you can guarantee that you have at most *N* processes running. And the worst case, you have a long queue, which you can cancel.

If you use a message queue, you can move the queue consumer onto another server (or servers). This helps spread server load if you have a lot of demand for your service. Running on another service also means limited access to data, which would be good for security, meaning the executable can't access files and memory it doesn't need to.

The downside is that this is asynchronous, and you need to notify that the file is ready for download. You also need to store it somewhere whilst it is waiting to be downloaded.

An upside to this is that the user isn't tying up a HTTP serving connection whilst waiting, and if it takes a long time to run the process, the user's connection won't time out.

Comment: Asynchronous and storage are a non-issue. Tools exist to solve both issues. AJAX and hard disks...

Comment: That's a puzzling comment. They *are* issues and they *do* affect design decisions. There are solutions, that doesn't stop them being issues.

Comment: Ill rephrase, they are not issues relevant to this context.

Comment: I'm happy to be proven wrong, but I disagree with you. You can't say "I have a design recommendation that involves X Y and Z" without mentioning that there are attendant issues A, B and C. For example,  what if it's running on a system without access to disk space? What if you need to talk to the ops guys to add new infrastructure to hold the files?

Comment: The question was that of vulnerability with an additional consideration of bots. In the domain of server side security, the synchronicity of client side interactions is out of scope. In the domain of server side security, storing a file is out of scope. On way or another, the client will be notified that their download is ready. The only way to bot-proof is to use a captcha. This is not file storage, or a synchronicity issue (captcha could be done before the process is even started). I only bring it up because we don't want to dilute the issue too much.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps we are using the word 'issue' in different ways.

Comment: I was overly ambiguous, I think

Comment: No problem, this conversation was useful in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Running process on server can not be a security flaw as is. As running a process in cases like yours is a *result* of some other action or operation requested by someone. So security flaw could be present in the methods/architecture that leads to that action that runs executable. If you feel secure enough on that layer, I would not be worry much about invoking a separate process, especially cause it brings more value to the service you offer.